# Add class to dynamically generated DOM element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a set of inputs (text boxes) which are added dynamically with the means of AJAX (`$.post()`). These input boxes have to be validated too. The validation works, but I can't seem to add any classes to the inputbox

```
  $("input[id^=code]").each(function() {
      if (!$.isNumeric($(this).val()) || $(this).val().length !== 6) {
          $(this).addClass("invalid");
      }
  })
```

The input boxes start with the id `code` and go like: `code1, code2, code3`

The html:

```
<div id="shoe_codes_maininput" style="display: table-cell;">
<div id="shoe_codes_row_1"> 
    <label class="shoe_code_label required">Shoe Code 1:<span class="star"> *</span></label> 
    <div class="shoe_code_input"><input placeholder="Enter the shoe code" id="code1" name="shoe[code_1]" class="required" maxlength="6"> </div> 
</div> 

<div id="shoe_codes_row_2"> 
    <label class="shoe_code_label required">Shoe Code 2:<span class="star"> *</span></label> 
    <div class="shoe_code_input"><input placeholder="Enter the shoe code" id="code2" name="shoe[code_2]" class="required" maxlength="6"> </div> 
</div> 
</div>
```

The Joomla submit function:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Joomla.submitbutton = function(task)
        {
            if (task == 'order.cancel') {
                Joomla.submitform(task, document.getElementById('order-form'));
            }
            else {
                var order = true;
                $("input[id^=code]").each(function() {
                    if (!$.isNumeric($(this).val()) || $(this).val().length !== 6) {
                        $(this).addClass("invalid");
                        order = false;
                    }
                })

                if (task != 'order.cancel' && document.formvalidator.isValid(document.id('order-form')) && order) {
                    Joomla.submitform(task, document.getElementById('order-form'));
                }
                else {
                    alert('<?php echo $this->escape(JText::_('JGLOBAL_VALIDATION_FORM_FAILED')); ?>');
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: what makes you say the class is not added? maybe it's a problem of selection, can you post the code where that class is needed?

Comment: Like Milind Anantwar said, you need to write the code in the success function. Otherwise it will be executed before the elements have been added in the DOM

Comment: If you remove the conditional statement and the code starts to work you can rule out any issues with your selectors. Then you can focus on the conditional.

Comment: Please show the rest of your code as the problem is likely to be with where it is placed.

Comment: Added the rest of the code

Answer (score 2):

You need to write the code in success function after appending the DOM in page.

```
success: function(){
//append input elements dynamically to page
 $("input[id^=code]").each(function() {
  if (!$.isNumeric($(this).val()) || $(this).val().length !== 6) {
      $(this).addClass("invalid");
  }
 });
}
```

Comment: I want the class to be added when the form is submitted (joomla admin form).  The form is submitted by javascript and not a regular submit button. Would that work with what you described?

Comment: @Ortixx: in that case you need to write the code on submit click.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the matching text in your selector with quotes.

```
$( "input[id^='code']" )
//            ^    ^
```

Checkout the documentation for more examples - http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

> jQuery( "[attribute^='value']" )

Comment: You only need to wrap it in quotes if it contains special characters (like `"-"` or `" "`)

Comment: There is no need to wrap it inside quotes since it dont have any metacharacters in it and it is a single word..

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - Not according to the documentation. Even the most basic of examples wrap the string.

Comment: The documentation is incomplete... In all attribute selectors the inner quotes are optional and only required if the string contains special characters (that would confuse the parser). Try it in a JSFiddle and see. In any case this does not answer the question (not my downvote BTW).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - hmm.. Well... That may be the case. Do you have any reference stating that the docs are incomplete?

Comment: Do the docs mention the quotes are optional? No? It is therefore self-evident from the absence they are incomplete :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - You might be relying on a bug in the implementation :) I would go by the docs and use the quotes explicitly - as the examples do... but that might just be me :)

Comment: @Lix `Attribute values in selector expressions must follow the rules for W3C CSS selectors; in general, that means anything other than a valid identifier should be surrounded by quotation marks.` [**Found it**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy: Thank you :) OK, the documentation is not *incomplete*. You just need to know where to look :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Ok, you tell me where should i look..? :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Oh fine. `You just need to know where to look` i was confused with this. :) :)